# Last Item in recyclerview is cut off

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, recyclerview-layout

I am using recyclerview to display a list of items and constraint layout is the parent view. The layout is displayed  below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Load the toolbar here -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_category"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Empty Category"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewContent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

The adapter layout for each row is presented below:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayoutImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonCart"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCoverArt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#59000000"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="$220"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLength="17"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:text="Add to Cart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

After running my application the layouts are presented in the image below:

[image]

I tried adding a bottom margin to the recycle view, but this has not resolved the issue. I used the following links as references: [RecyclerView is cutting off the last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742724/recyclerview-is-cutting-off-the-last-item/32743510), [RecyclerView cutting off last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097219/recyclerview-cutting-off-last-item) and tried making those changes with no luck

Comment: checkout my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742724/recyclerview-is-cutting-off-the-last-item/60314197#60314197

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your `RecyclerView` is not properly constrained. You can either use `0dp` (`MATCH_CONSTRAINT`) for the height and use all available space:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />
```

or if you want to keep it as `wrap_content` you will need to set `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` attribute to enforce the constraints:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />
```

Comment: I actually had to use `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` as the attribute in question here is the height of the recyclerview, not the width.

Comment: I had a RecyclerView inside a DialogFragment, and `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` fixed it

Comment: This worked like a charm. Changin recyclerView Height to 0dp  did not show any items for me. thanks @Pawel

Answer (score 5):

I tried all the available option from most of possible site but I didn't get the solution.
Then, I think can I use bottom padding? And Yes, It's work for me.

I am sharing the code to you.
Nothing more attribute required other than height, width & padding.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/your id name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/your field" />
```

Answer (score 4):

1)The View of Recyclerview must be properly constrained. (by ConstraintLayout or any other layout parameters).

2)The Last item occupies the space ***inside*** the RecyclerView, hence use ***Padding***. (e.g android:paddingBottom="50dp")

3)Use ***android:clipToPadding="false"*** in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Well in my case my `ConstraintLayout`'s `layout_height` was `wrap_content`, that's why last item was cutting from bottom. So to resolve this: **`ConstraintLayout`'s `layout_height` should be either fixed or `match_parent`.**

Answer (score 0):

**Try using `RelativeLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout`.**

It's working for me so it seems a problem with ConstraintLayout specifically.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:clipToPadding="false"

android:paddingBottom="10dp"
```

Did the trick for me, After multiple tries.