# Recyclerview Height cutoff

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

**This is the structure of my layout:**

```
<ScrollView
-height - match>
<CoordinatorLayout
-height - wrap>
<AppbarLayout
-height - wrap>
<CollapsingToolbarLayout
-height - wrap>
<ConstraintLayout>
//min height is set dynamically.
</ConstraintLayout>
</CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</AppbarLayout>
<RecyclerView
->scroll behaviour
->height-wrap/>
<CoordinatorLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

*because the scroll view is present I cannot apply the min-height in collapsing toolbar layout. is there any way we can adjust the height(here my recycler view gets cutoff)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this property to recylerview `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"`.

See the following for more details 
[Last Item in recyclerview is cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342917/last-item-in-recyclerview-is-cut-off)

Comment: Hey Joseph try to update height to  'android:layout_height="0dp" '